# How to adjust arrow head size of arrow-node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-shape

I am trying to use `single arrow` node from `shapes.arrows` TikZ library. The problem is with the proper adjustment of the arrow tip span - with the argument `single arrow head extend`.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [single arrow,draw,inner sep=0,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm,single arrow head extend=0.2cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Combining `minimum width` with `single arrow head extend` seems buggy. Use `inner sep` instead to define the inner width:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [single arrow,draw,inner sep=1cm,minimum height=4cm, single arrow head extend=0.8cm,anchor=west] (a) {};
    \draw[|<->|, purple, ultra thin] (0,0) -- (4,0) node [midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 4 cm};
    \draw[|<->|, red, ultra thin] (0,0) -- (0,1) node [midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 1 cm};
    \draw[|<->|, blue, ultra thin] (a.before head) -- ++(0,0.8) node [midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 0.8 cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrowheadsized]

Update: the final size of the arrow could still be larger than intended, as caused by the finite line width and default `miter` line join option, illustrated below.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{samplearrow/.style={single arrow,draw,inner sep=1cm,minimum height=4cm, single arrow head extend=0.8cm,anchor=west,line width=5mm}}
    \node [samplearrow, orange!50] (a) {};
    \node [samplearrow, gray,line join=round] (b) {};
    \draw[|<->|, purple, ultra thin] (0.5,0) -- ++(4,0) node [midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 4 cm};
    \draw[|<->|, red, ultra thin] (0,0) -- (0,1) node [midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 1 cm};
    \draw[|<->|, blue, ultra thin] (a.before head) -- ++(0,0.8) node [midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 0.8 cm};
    \draw[|<->|, ultra thin] (0,1) -- ++(0,0.5) node [midway, above, sloped] {\tiny 5 mm};
    \draw[|<->|, ultra thin] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) node [pos=0, left, sloped] {\tiny 5 mm};
    \draw[<-,orange] (a.before tip) -- ++(-0.2,0) node[left] {\tiny miter};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: fatarrowheadsized]

This could be solved by subtracting the line width from both the `inner sep` and `minimum height` (e.g. `inner sep=1cm-0.4pt` for the default case of using a `thin` line), and by setting `line join` to `round` (as illustrated in gray) or `bevel`.

Comment: If this node is aligned to the rectangular node then it is visible the difference between the sizes of these nodes - it equals one width of the line.

Comment: @forrest Yes, there are actually two reasons why the arrow does not fit the rectangle. One is, as you mentioned, the finite line width (which increases both the width and length of the arrow). The other is the effect of the `miter` line join. I'll update the answer with a fat arrow to show the effect of both. The former could be solved by subtracting the line width (`0.4pt` for the default `thin` line), the latter by switching to a `round` or `bevel` line join.